# Understanding feedback =1 and comparing with a system with no feedback

Tags: linear-systems, signal-processing

I was studying this system
[image]

In this V its a Voltage in a circuit and V_c its the voltage in a capacitor, the circuit was not provided, then calculated the step response (well I was told the step response shows the system response in time) and its

$1-e^{-t}$

and then look at this other system
[image]

and based on block reductions
[image]

The ratio $\frac{V_{c}}{V}$ is

$\frac{1}{(s+1)(1\pm1)}$

then you have two cases

- $\frac{1}{(s+1)(2)}$
- $\frac{1}{(s+1)(0)}$

How should be interpreted this cases, I understand the first response its stable but the 0 in the second makes inestable the second case, isnt supossed that feedbak should stabilizate the systems?

Update
At first it seemed to me that both systems were the same then doing the correct block algebra I have seen that arent the same. And thats the question I was doing.
Thanks

Comment: A few remarks: the second schematic, as is, represents two paralleled systems, not a feedback one. In fact, there's no summing node. Have you exactly reproduced the original schematics?

Comment: I have updated the second scheme (I dont know hoe to draw the summing node, but in fact that black circle is one) Thanks

Comment: The denominator is $1+GH$, not $1+H$.

Comment: Before I answer: these are impedances, right? Is $s$ meant to be an imaginary measure of frequency like $s = i\omega$ (or $j\omega$ if you prefer the electrical engineers' conventions) ?

Comment: @CRDrost Although the question is not well written, the only reasonable interpretation in the context is that $s$ is the complex frequency because those functions are transfer functions in the Laplace domain (or $s$-domain).

Comment: @CRDrost, they're transfer functions, not impedances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear to me what you're doing in the final sections of your post but the transfer function of the second system is easily found to be

$$\frac{V_C(s)}{V(s)} = \frac{1}{s + 2}$$

as follows.  By inspection,

$$V_C(s) = \frac{V(s) - V_C(s)}{s + 1}$$

Gather like terms,

$$V_C(s) + \frac{V_C(s)}{s+1} = \frac{V(s)}{s+1}$$

Simplify,
$$V_C(s)\left(1 + \frac{1}{s+1}\right) = \frac{V(s)}{s+1}$$

$$V_C(s) = \frac{V(s)}{s+1}\frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{s+1}} = \frac{V(s)}{s + 2}$$

and the result follows.  The second system clearly has 100% negative feedback and the transfer function is that of a 1st order low-pass filter with a pole at $s = -2$ and so is stable (pole is in the left-half plane).

If the feedback were positive instead, we would start with

$$V_C(s) = \frac{V(s) + V_C(s)}{s + 1}$$

leading to the transfer function

$$\frac{V_C(s)}{V(s)} = \frac{1}{s}$$

which is the transfer function of an integrator which has a pole at $s = 0$.

Now, given the above, what is your question?